Derivation of Gibbs phase rule
I learnt about the Gibbs phase rule a while back but did not really think too much about how it was derived. I am now currently looking back at the derivation provided in the textbook and I realised that there are some parts of it that I don't fully understand.
The Gibbs phase rule simply says that to completely specify the intensive state of a system with $N$ species and $\pi$ phases, we need to specify $2+N-\pi$ variables. For example, if there is a binary mixture of acetone and ethanol ($N = 2$) in a closed system, where there is both a liquid and vapour phase ($\pi = 2$), then there are $2+2-2 = 2$ free variables that needs to be specified for the system to be fully determined. For example, these could be the mole fractions of ethanol in each phase, or they could also be the temperature and pressure of the system.
Its derivation is just based on considerations of the number of unknowns and the number of independent equations. For example, if there are $5$ independent equations and $6$ unknowns, then there is $6-5=1$ degree of freedom, or $1$ free variable which we can specify to fully define the system. If we have $N$ species and $\pi$ phases, then we have $(N-1)\pi +2$ unknown variables. This is because, in each phase, we only need to know $N-1$ mole fractions, as all the mole fractions in each phase sum to $1$. The temperature and pressure of the system are also unknowns.
It is known that there are $(\pi-1)N$ independent equations for closed system of $N$ species in $\pi$ phases, at equilibrium. I am not exactly sure how these equations come about. I am guessing that by the fact that the species are in chemical equilibrium, we are able to write down equations satisfying Raoult's Law, of the form $x_i P_i^{sat} = y_i P$. We can write one Raoult's law equation for each species, if there were only 2 phases. If there were 3 phases, say solid, liquid and gas, we could write Raoult's Law equation (based on equality of fugacity) for the solid-liquid equilibrium, liquid-gas equilibrium, and solid-gas equilibrium, but they would be constitute a dependent system of equations, and so there are really only 2 independent sets of Raoult's Law equations? Is my understanding correct?
Finally, we have $(N-1)\pi +2$ unknown variables and $(\pi-1)N$ independent equations, so the number of degrees of freedom would be $(N-1)\pi + 2 - (\pi-1)N = 2 + N - \pi$.

rather than using Raoult's law the derivation of the number of equations uses the fact that the chemical potential of each phase is equal, as is the temperature and pressure. A thorough derivation is given in Zemanski & Dittman, 'Heat & Thermodynamics' 6th ed. publ. McGraw-Hill. It is far too long to include here.

Ah ok I see, that makes sense. Raoult's Law is also derived from the equality of fugacities/chemical potentials. I am actually wondering why it must be $(N-1)\pi$ equations. Is my reasoning correct, especially in the case where there are 3 phases, solid, liquid and gas? My reasoning is that of the 3 sets, solid-gas, solid-liquid and liquid-gas, only two sets of the equations are independent.

Fluffy bear strikes back ;p (sorry, was hard to resist.) And it's even second post this year!

@Mithoron Lol... I'm currently studying a chemical engineering course, which is mostly physics with some physical chemistry content, e.g. thermodynamics and kinetics. Hence, my rate of question-asking on this site has decreased

@porphyrin Thanks for the reference! The derivation provided in that textbook you referenced is sufficiently detailed and more than answers my questions

Ech, you can ask chemical engineering too, can't say I like it, though ;)

The remaining equations you point in your answer refer to the chemical equilibrium established between all the species across all the phases. I illustrate the scenario that you raised in the comments as to explain this.

Say we have $3$ species which are in equilibrium across three phases, namely solid, liquid, and gas which are denoted with $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ respectively. The mechanical and thermal equilibrium imposes
\begin{align}
  p^\alpha = p^\beta = p^\gamma \equiv p \tag{1} \\
  T^\alpha = T^\beta = T^\gamma \equiv T \tag{2} \\
\end{align}
Let $z_j^\delta$ denote the composition of species $j$ in phase $\delta$. The chemical equilibrium imposes
\begin{gather}
  \text{Chem. eq.}:
  \begin{cases}
    \mu_1^\alpha(p,T,\{z\}^\alpha) =
    \mu_1^\beta(p,T,\{z\}^\beta) =
    \mu_1^\gamma(p,T,\{z\}^\gamma) \\
    \mu_2^\alpha(p,T,\{z\}^\alpha) =
    \mu_2^\beta(p,T,\{z\}^\beta) =
    \mu_2^\gamma(p,T,\{z\}^\gamma) \\
    \mu_3^\alpha(p,T,\{z\}^\alpha) =
    \mu_3^\beta(p,T,\{z\}^\beta) =
    \mu_3^\gamma(p^,T,\{z\}^\gamma) \\
  \end{cases} \tag{CE}
\end{gather}
As you said, there are three constraints as the molar fractions sum up to one
\begin{align}
  z_1^\alpha + z_2^\alpha + z_3^\alpha &= 1 \tag{3} \\
  z_1^\beta  + z_2^\beta  + z_3^\beta  &= 1 \tag{4} \\
  z_1^\gamma + z_2^\gamma + z_3^\gamma &= 1 \tag{5}
\end{align}
Gibbs' phase rules states that we need $2 - \pi + N = 2 - 3 + 3 = 2$ variables to fix the intensive state of the thermodynamic system. We count:

The unknowns are $p$, $T$, and $9$ molar fractions, so we have $11$ unknowns.
The system "CE" gives us $6$ equations, and Eqs. (3,4,5) gives us $3$ more equations. Therefore, we have $9$ equations.
$11 - 9 = 2$, so we need to fix two variables, as stated by Gibbs' phase rule.


Your idea of writing a set of 'Raoult's laws' is equivalent to write equations for the chemical equilibrium. In fact, this is the simplest way for a mathematical equation in L-V equilibrium. You can write the set of equations 'CE' with fugacities and they are totally equivalent. The most important problem in equilibrium thermodynamics is to find these fugacities as a function of the state variables. From a theoretical perspective, they give us information about the interaction between several species in the different states of aggregation, at least at the macroscopic scale. For practical purposes, they are widely used for mass transfer operations in the industry.
For example, every equation of state gives a chemical potential. I will give you another example aside from Raoult's law. The LV equilibrium can be solved by using the van der Waals' equation of state, because every equation of states establishes a chemical potential as a function of the variables. It is possible to prove that the fugacity for species $1$ in a binary mixture is
\begin{equation}
  f_1(p,T,y_1) = \color{blue}{
  \exp\left[\left(b_1 - \frac{a_1}{RT}\right)\frac{p}{RT}\right]
  \exp\left[\frac{(\sqrt{a_1} - \sqrt{a_2})^2(1 - y_1)^2p}{(RT)^2}\right]}
  y_1p
\end{equation}
We recover the ideal equation of state with $a_1 = a_2 = 0$ and $b_1 = b_2 = 0$, and the fugacity in the gas phase is equal to the partial pressure. This is the fugacity shown in Raoult's law. The part in blue is the correction given by the van der Waals' equation of state.
In addition, if the gas phase is very pure in species $1$, then $1 - y_1 \to 0$. The second exponential tends to one and only the first one remains. If you remember, this is the exact expression for the fugacity coefficient of a pure species given by van der Waals EoS.

References
Information about the 'chemical equilibrium problem' and Gibbs' phase rule can be read in Chapter 1 and the first appendix in:

J. M. Prausnitz, R. N. Lichtenhaler, E. G. de Azevedo, "Molecular Thermodynamics of Fluid-Phase Equilibria, 3rd ed., Prentice Hall PTR, 1999.


That's a great answer! Clarifies all my doubts, and now I also know that there exists expressions for fugacities of species in non-ideal mixtures. I was not taught that in my chemical engineering thermodynamics class

@TanYongBoon Thanks. Tan, I made a mistake in the set of equations 'CE'. The chemical potential for a single species depends in general of all molar fractions within that phase, which I put between curly braces. If you are interested, there are many models for the non-ideality in the liquid phase: Wilson, NRTL, Scatchard-Hildebrand, UNIQUAC, etc. For the gas phase, virial coefficients are a common option.
